# How can I use pnpm within my electron application?

Tags: node.js, electron, pnpm

I'm wanting to use pnpm instead of the tradition npm or yarn to decrease the possibility of installing duplicate modules in my node_modules, as well as to reduce the size of the node_modules, but whenever I pack my app using electron-builder, upon launch I throw the error "Error: Cannot find module 'builder-util-runtime'". I've read in some git forums that it stems from an error processing the node_modules and pnpm-lock.yaml within the electron asar and I was wondering if anyone has found any solutions to this.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "toolbox",
  "version": "2.0.12",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "electron": "electron ./build/app.js",
    "webpack": "webpack --mode production",
    "react": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --port 3000",
    "electron-dev": "cross-env ELECTRON_ENV=dev electron ./build/app.js",
    "webpack-prod": "webpack --mode production",
    "build-win": "electron-builder build --win -c.extraMetadata.main=./build/app.js --publish never"
  },
  "author": "Toolbox",
  "license": "ISC",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.Toolbox",
    "productName": "Toolbox",
    "files": [
      "build/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "Functions/**/*",
      "Modules/**/*",
      "src/**/*"
    ],
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "spaces",
        "name": "toolbox",
        "region": "nyc3"
      }
    ],
    "win": {
      "icon": "toolbox.ico",
      "target": "nsis"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "installerIcon": "toolbox.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "toolbox.ico",
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@electron/remote": "^2.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "ansi-colors": "^4.1.3",
    "autosolve-http-client": "^1.0.5",
    "csv-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "deepmerge": "^4.3.1",
    "discord-rpc": "^4.0.1",
    "discord-webhook-node": "^1.1.8",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "electron-store": "^8.1.0",
    "electron-updater": "^6.1.7",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fast-csv": "^4.3.6",
    "fetch-cookie": "^2.1.0",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^7.0.2",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.6.3",
    "ip": "^1.1.8",
    "mailparser": "^3.6.5",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.44",
    "mongodb": "^6.3.0",
    "node-fetch": "2.6.11",
    "node-html-parser": "^6.1.11",
    "node-imap": "^0.9.6",
    "node-machine-id": "^1.1.12",
    "node-notifier": "^10.0.1",
    "node-random-name": "^1.0.1",
    "node-wav-player": "^0.2.0",
    "puppeteer": "^21.6.1",
    "puppeteer-extra": "^3.3.6",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.11.2",
    "quoted-printable": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.2",
    "systeminformation": "^5.21.20",
    "tough-cookie": "^4.1.3",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "v8-compile-cache": "^2.4.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0",
    "winston": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.9.0",
    "electron": "^28.1.3",
    "electron-builder": "^24.9.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.4",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.4",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to pack `node_modules`, it will just make your app heavy. Bundle all your files with webpack and then only package the bundled files, problem solved.

Comment: I wasn't really asking about how to reduce my application size, but more on the error of "Error: Cannot find module 'builder-util-runtime'" when using pnpm instead of npm or yarn

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote a comment and not an answer. I gave you a workaround. Feel free to use it or ignore it.